# Программно задать Grid.Row и Grid.Column

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Программно собираю разметку XAML:

```
private Grid MakeGrid()
{
    Grid grid = new Grid();

    ColumnDefinition cd1 = new ColumnDefinition();
    ColumnDefinition cd2 = new ColumnDefinition();
    cd1.Width = new GridLength(50);

    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd1);
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd2);

    RowDefinition rd1 = new RowDefinition();
    RowDefinition rd2 = new RowDefinition();
    rd1.Height = new GridLength(50);

    return grid;
}

private Polyline MakeArrow()
{
    Polyline pl = new Polyline();
    /*Тут нужно задать Grid.Row="0" и Grid.Column="0"*/
    return pl;
}
```

Необходимо вложить "стрелочку" `Polyline` в первую строку первого столбца `Grid`. Не могу найти как это правильно написать.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Решение удалось найти. На месте комментария пишем

```
Grid.SetRow(pl, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(pl, 0);
```

Где 0 - это позиция элемента.
Второй вариант:

```
pl.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
pl.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
```